# In cypress Is there any method to run 3 dependent forms individually?

Tags: cypress, bdd

I have 3 forms, and one form is depending on other 2 forms(Each form is in each test file), So my question is **can i know is there any solution(method) to run those 3 forms individually?**
(The purpose is i want to run each forms individually)

This is **maker** form
[image: This is maker form]

This is **Category** form
[image: This is Category form]

This is **maker type** form
[image: This is maker type form]

These are the three forms which i have mentioned above.
**Maker form**, and **Category** form are depending on **Maker type** form, (The value i'm adding in **maker** and **Category** forms as above images, will have to choose from **Maker type** form)
So these Each three forms are in each test files.
When i run the test i can not run the **maker type** form individually, because its' maker and category values are taken by Maker form and Category form added values.

Comment: Are you doing any http requests in between showing the forms? If so then you could tap into the http interception features of Cypress to send faked data back from the server.

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you provide some sample code of how the forms interact and snapshots of the dome elements

Answer (score 1):

Your tests (e2e tests) should follow the user flow, so if one form requires another to complete the task, then that's how you test them.

BUT you can test forms independently using **Component Testing**. In this type of test you mount just one component (form) at a time and supply input values (normally coming from the other forms) via ***props***.

Here is some info about it [My Vision for Component Tests in Cypress](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/my-vision-for-component-tests/)